# How to pass variables from the Django view to a template

Tags: python, django

I want to pass a variable from views.py to home.html.
I tried everything I could and I am new to django.

It doesn't give any error but it doesn't display the variable as well.
I may have made mistakes in url.py or settings.py

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'project1'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    name = "kiran"
    key = 123
    context = {
        'name': name,
        'key': key,
    }
    return render(request, 'templates/home.html', context)
```

home.html

```
<h>hello</h>
<h3>{{key}}</h3>
```

the page although displays hello but not {{key}}
this is just an attempt to try if it's working but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `templates` in wrong way and also confusing class-based view with function-based view.

> **urls.py**

```
from project1.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='home'),
]
```

and then in views just pass `'home.html'`.

> **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    name = "kiran"
    key = 123
    context = {
        'name': name,
        'key': key,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
]
```

with

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
]
```

Your code is mostly correct, but the URL is not calling your view function (`index` in your case). It is using a Class-Based-View with the `home.html` template.

Comment: why have you passed index? It gives me error "name index is not defined

Comment: You have to define your route with a callable. In your case you were using the default TemplateView(). However, you need to pass the index() function. I see that in your urls.py you are importing views (`from . import views`), so `views.index` should be defined.

Comment: I tried this too, it shows error.  File "C:\Users\kiran.tanweer\Envs\celery\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the way you are importing
Try importing the views like `from project1 import views` and then change this `path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home')` to `path('', views.index, name='home')`

Comment: this is incorrect: it should be `views.index`, without parentheses

Comment: Yep sorry about that I'll change it.. Thanx for identifying.

Comment: Now it says TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Comment: I have solved it. in my views.py changed  return render(request, 'templates/home.html', context) to     return render(request, 'home.html', context)